# Flutter app reloading widgets without fetching data from internet again

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Currently, I'm fetching data using HTTP requests. The resulting data is shown in a `ScrollSnapList` and when selecting a different item of that list to be centered I also want other data to be shown below.

```
ScrollSnapList(
   onItemFocus: () {
      setState() { //set current index }
   },
   itemSize: 35,
   itemBuilder: _buildListItem,
   itemCount: data.length,
   reverse: true,
),
```

When a different item is getting focused I call `setState` to reload the bottom widget to show the correct data. In the background, all my HTTP requests are getting called again which isn't needed since all data is already loaded. How am I able to only reload the widgets without requesting all HTTP requests again? The results of the HTTP calls are visualized in a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: fetching data in `initState`

Comment: Do all widgets then show up without data while loading or does the app show nothing while fetching data in `initState`? Because I don't want the user to just see nothing happen while loading the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working by just moving the FutureBuilder to `initState`.